# A problem involving sum of digits of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, decimal-expansion

**Question:** The sum of the digits of a natural number $n$ is denoted by $S(n)$. Prove that $S(8n) \ge \frac{1}{8}S(n)$ for each $n \in \mathbb N$.
[source:Latvia 1995]

At first I thought this problem can be solved using induction on the number of digits. Say without the leftmost digit (say $a_n$) of $n$ the number becomes $n'$. Then I tried to find some relation between $S(n)$ and $S(n')$ also $S(8n)$ and $S(8n')$. But that doesn't seem to  be working in general.

I don't have much experience dealing with sums of digits, it seems somewhat random. Apart from any hint or solution in this problem, I am also interested in general strategies or any references in order to deal with such digit-sum problems. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $S(n)$ is just one iteration?  That is $S(57489574269789435)= 5+7+4+8+9+5+7+4+2+6+9+7+8+9+4+3+5=102$ full stop?  We *don't* keep going?  We *don't* do $S(57489574269789435)=S(102) = 3$?

Comment: That sounds like the most natural interpretation of "the sum of the digits".

Comment: Yeah, but so often you get a question (such as a modulo 9 question) that assumes it's recursive....

Comment: Maybe try to prove that $S(2n)\ge S(\frac n2)$ and apply three times ?

Comment: @fleablood No,its just one iteration.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Did you mean $\frac 12\times S(n)$?  But in that case, taking $n=5$ we have $S(10)=1$ while $S(5)=5$.  The analogous example for $8$ would be $n=125$, but that just yields equality, since $8\times S(1000)=S(125)$.

Comment: @lulu: yes you are right. I submitted this " in case", I didn't seriously check.

Comment: Appreciate you giving the source. +1

Comment: @lulu Your example with $125$ was the key. Thanks for giving it!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a very elegant solution you found.

Comment: Okay... so do it will induction for numbers with $3n$ digits.  The only catch is $S(125)= \frac 18 S(1000=8*125)$.  Other wise it's no where near as small.  Now if $S(8M) \le \frac 18SM$ then $S(10^{3k}A + M)$ where $A$ is $3$ digit will have $8(10^{3k}A + M = 10^{3^k}(8A +$ carried digit $) + (8M - 10^{3k}$carried digit$)  Now $S(8A+$carried digit $ can be shown be example to fit and so on... the details may be tedious and picayune but I think it will work..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For all natural numbers $a,b$ we have:

- $S(10a)=S(a)$, and
- $S(a+b)\le S(a)+S(b)$, with equality only when there is no carry when doing the grade school addition $a+b$.

A consequence of these is that for all natural numbers $n$
$$
\begin{aligned}
S(125n)&=S(100n+20n+5n)\\
&\le S(100n)+S(20n)+S(5n)\\
&=S(n)+S(2n)+S(5n)\\
&=S(n)+S(n+n)+S(n+n+n+n+n)\\
&\le 8S(n).
\end{aligned}
$$
In other words,
$$S(n)\ge\frac18 S(125n).$$

Plugging in $n=8m$ gives, for all natural numbers $m$, the inequality
$$
S(8m)\ge\frac18 S(1000m)=\frac18 S(m).
$$

Comment: It seems likely to me that the inequality is strict unless $n=8m$ is a power of ten. So the examples of equality that Lulu found are the only ones. It is mighty hard not to get a carry in $n+n+n+n+n$ :-)

Comment: Wrong. $m=11000=8\cdot 1375$ also works. It is instructive (at least to me) to check all the inequalities in this case also. The next counterexample is an exercise for the reader :-)